# (Terraform, GCP) Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project myProject. Details:[], forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to make **a VPC** on **GCP** with the **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myProject"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name = "main"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}
```

And this is **my project name**, **number** and **ID**:

[image]

But I got this error below:

```
Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project myProject.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
      {
        "description": "Google developer console API key",
        "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/myProject/apiui/credential"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "consumer": "projects/myProject",
      "service": "compute.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "CONSUMER_INVALID"
  }
]
, forbidden

  with google_compute_network.vpc,
  on 1st.tf line 25, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc":
  25: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
```

Are there any mistakes with my **Terraform** code?

Comment: Did you read [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started)? It is well described in documentation. There is an information that you should your own project in example snippet `project = "{{YOUR GCP PROJECT}}"` also in below description you can find that information also `The project field should be your personal project id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put **the project ID "myproject-338117"** to **"project"** instead of **the project name "myProject"**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-338117" // Put the project id "myproject-338117"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name = "main"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}
```

Actually, **the key name "project"** is not clear and intuitive to put **a project ID**. A lot of people will mistakenly put **a project name** instead of **a project ID**.